# Handling unused return statements

Tags: java, c#, coding-style

I have the following code :

```
public static QHttpResponse SafeExecute(QHttpRequest request, int retries, int sleep)
{
    if (retries < 1)
        throw new Exception("retries must be at least 1");

    for (int index = 0; index < retries; index++)
    {
        try
        {
            return QWebClient.Execute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (index == retries - 1)
                throw;

            Thread.Sleep(sleep);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The second return in this function never does anything. Would it be better to use `return null` or `throw new Exception("Shouldn't be here")`?

Or should I completely avoid this situation by storing the result in a variable and returning it? (Which seems unnecessary)

Comment: it's reachable code (when `retries` is zero)

Comment: add a language tag. (This looks like Java. In C++ the solution would be to just not have a return statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for paths that should be unreachable by design, it makes sense to throw an exception. Also as an explicit way to document that that is the intended operation of your method.

An "InvalidLogicException" would be nice, but does not exist.

In c# the most "appropriate" kinda exception types available might be one of the following:

```
throw new InvalidProgramException("BUG: This code should be unreachable by design");
throw new InvalidOperationException("BUG: This code should be unreachable by design");
throw new NotSupportedException("BUG: This code should be unreachable by design");
```

Comment: Seems a bit messy tbh. I'll wait a few days to see if a better solution turns up